# Nodejs utilise aliases to run python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have an express app running on my ubuntu machine with some python scripts. As you all know Ubuntu 16.04 comes with default `python 2.7` version, which is not what i need so i created an alias `alias python='/usr/bin/python3'` , so now everytime i run python in my terminal i can see version `3.5` which is exactly what I need, however.

The issue is, when i try to start my server it tells me `Error: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. After doing a bit of debugging I've found out that its still using `2.7` apparently aliases are not important for nodejs or config.json as it goes inside of the `/usr/bin` and starts searching for `python` folder instead of using alias.

EDIT: Using PythonShell

Question: How can i make it use aliases, so when its `python` its `python3` for nodejs.